# How to separate text on different lines in an email using ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, android-intent

I was wondering, if anyone could help with this problem, I'm having trouble with ACTION_SEND. I have it setup that all the info is sent to the e-mail and to the address. My problem is I'm not sure if I can or if it possible to separate the information on different lines.

I would like to have my 1's item on one line and my 2's item on another line. I'm trying to get all my different number items to be put on different lines in the e-mail. Is that possible or do I need to redo the code to get that to happen?

Thank you in advance for your help and time!

Here's my code:

```
String message = pIN1 + " " + pD1 + " " + passM1 + " " + pU1 + " " + pIN2 + " " + pD2 + " " + passM2 + " " + pU2;

String[] to=new String[]{""};
String subject = ("Results");
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

if (passSN.equals("2")){
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email"));
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the new line character **\n** to achieve what you want:

```
String message = pIN1 + "\n" + pD1 + "\n" + passM1;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Hi Natan Felipe, Thank you for the reply. I will try doing this tomorrow and I will see if it works. Then I will let you know.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you Natan for your suggestion. I made the changes to the code and tried it out and it worked. All my items were on different lines. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No worries @Mike, I'm happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
    String message = "";
    message += pIN1 + " " + pD1 + " " + passM1 + " " + pU1;
    message += "\n" + pIN2 + " " + pD2 + " " + passM2 + " " + pU2;

    String[] to = new String[]{""};
    String subject = ("Results");
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email"));
```

Comment: Hi Chornge, Thank you for the reply. I will try your suggestion out tomorrow and see if it works. Then I will let you know.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you chornge for your suggestion. I have my problem fix now but I appreciate your help, time and suggestion. Since you have the right answer as well, I'm going to give you a +1 on your answer because you suggest adding "\n" to the code as well. Thank you very much for your suggestion.